# JQuery - Dropdown selected option value is not passed to ajax query parameter (Metronic Template)

Tags: jquery, laravel, metronic

I'm trying to pass dropdown selected option to AJAX query parameter and i'm getting **null** in the payload.
If I `console.log()` the selected option, I can get the correct value, but it seems I can't pass it to AJAX query parameter option.

What can be worng in my code?

This is the HTML code section for these dropdowns:

```
<label class="col-form-label">{{ __('general.labels.marketcenter') }}</label>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-sm-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="kt_market_center_dropdown">
        <option value=""></option>
        @foreach($market_center_dropdown as $market_center)
        <option value="{{ $market_center->id }}">{{ $market_center->mc_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<label class="col-form-label">{{ __('general.labels.megaagent') }}</label>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-sm-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="kt_mega_agent_dropdown">
        <option value=""></option>
        @foreach($mega_agent_dropdown as $mega_agent)
        <option value="{{ $mega_agent->id }}">{{ $mega_agent->megaagent_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<label class="col-form-label">{{ __('general.labels.teams') }}</label>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-sm-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="kt_team_dropdown">
        <option value=""></option>
        @foreach($teams_dropdown as $teams)
        <option value="{{ $teams->id }}">{{ $teams->team_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

This is my javascript code (the `console.log($("#kt_market_center_dropdown option:selected").val());` code is getting the correct value from dropdown and is the same code in ajax query parameter)

```
"use strict";
var KTDatatableChildRemoteDataDemo = {
    init: function () {
        var t;
        t = $(".kt-datatable").KTDatatable({
                data: {
                    type: "remote",
                    source: {
                        read: {
                           url: "/dashboard/exclusive",
                           method: 'GET',
                           dataType: "json",
                           contentType: "application/json",
                           params: {
                            query: {
                                market_center: $("#kt_market_center_dropdown option:selected").val(),
                                mega_agent: $("#kt_mega_agent_dropdown option:selected").val(),
                                team: $("#kt_team_dropdown option:selected").val()                                            
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10,
                    serverPaging: !0,
                    serverFiltering: !1,
                    serverSorting: !0
                },
                layout: {
                    scroll: !0,
                    height: 1000,
                    footer: !1
                },
                sortable: false,
                toolbar: { 
                    items: {
                        info: false,
                    }    
                },
                pagination: !0,
                detail: {
                    title: "Cargando tabla",
                    content: function (t) {
                        $("<div/>").attr("id", "child_data_ajax_" + t.data.id).appendTo(t.detailCell).KTDatatable({
                            data: {
                                type: "remote",
                                source: {
                                    read: {
                                        url: "/dashboard/exclusive/details",
                                        method: 'GET',
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        contentType: "application/json",
                                        params: {
                                            query: {
                                                id: t.data.id,
                                                exclusive: $('#kt_form_exclusive').prop("checked") ? "Exclusiva" : "",
                                                open: $('#kt_form_open').prop("checked") ? "No Exclusiva" : "",
                                                sale: $('#kt_form_sale').prop("checked") ? "Venta" : "",
                                                rent: $('#kt_form_rent').prop("checked") ? "Alquiler" : ""                                                
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                pageSize: 10,
                                serverPaging: true,
                                serverFiltering: true,
                                serverSorting: true
                            },
                            layout: {
                                scroll: !0,
                                height: 800,
                                footer: false,
                                spinner: {
                                    type: 1,
                                    theme: "default"
                                }
                            },
                            sortable: false,
                            toolbar: { 
                                items: {
                                    info: false,
                                }    
                            },
                            translate: {
                                records: {
                                    noRecords: 'No se encontraron registros',
                                    processing: 'Por favor espere...'
                                },
                                toolbar: {
                                    pagination: {
                                        items: {
                                            default: {
                                                first: 'Primero',
                                                prev: 'Anterior',
                                                next: 'Siguiente',
                                                last: 'Ultimo',
                                                more: 'Más',
                                                input: 'Nro. Página',
                                                select: 'Seleccione cantidad',
                                                all: 'todos',
                                            },
                                            info: 'Mostrando {{start}} - {{end}} of {{total}}',
                                        },
                                    },
                                }
                            },
                            rows: {
                                beforeTemplate: function(row, data, index) {
                                    if (data.prop_type == 'TOTAL CANTIDAD' || data.prop_type == 'TOTAL VOLUMEN') {
                                        $(row).css('background-color', '#F7F8FA');
                                     }
                                },   
                              },
                            columns: [ {
                                    field: "prop_type",
                                    title: "Tipo",
                                    width: 110
                                }, {
                                    field: "ENE",
                                    title: "ENE",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                }, {
                                    field: "FEB",
                                    title: "FEB",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                }, {
                                    field: "MAR",
                                    title: "MAR",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                },{
                                    field: "ABR",
                                    title: "ABR",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                },{
                                    field: "MAY",
                                    title: "MAY",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                },{
                                    field: "JUN",
                                    title: "JUN",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                },{
                                    field: "JUL",
                                    title: "JUL",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                },{
                                    field: "AGO",
                                    title: "AGO",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                },{
                                    field: "SEP",
                                    title: "SEP",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                },{
                                    field: "OCT",
                                    title: "OCT",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                },{
                                    field: "NOV",
                                    title: "NOV",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                },{
                                    field: "DIC",
                                    title: "DIC",
                                    width: 70,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                },{
                                    field: "TOTAL",
                                    title: "TOTAL",
                                    width: 80,
                                    textAlign: "center",
                                    type: "number"
                                }
                                
                            ]
                        })
                    }
                },
                search: {
                    input: $("#generalSearch")
                },
                columns: [{
                        field: "id",
                        title: "",
                        sortable: !1,
                        width: 30,
                        textAlign: "center"
                    },{
                        field: "name",
                        title: "Asociado",
                        width: 200,
                        autoHide: false,
                        sortable: false,
                        // callback function support for column rendering
                        template: function (data) {                
                            var output = '';
                            if(data.avatar) {
                                output = '' +
                                '<div class="kt-user-card-v2">' +
                                '<div class="kt-user-card-v2__pic">' +
                                '<img src="' + data.avatar + '" alt="photo">' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="kt-user-card-v2__details">' +
                                '<a href="#" class="kt-user-card-v2__name">' + data.name + '</a>' +
                                '<span class="kt-user-card-v2__desc">' + data.role + '</span>' +
                                '<span class="kt-user-card-v2__desc"></span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</div>';
                            } else {
                                output = '' +
                                '<div class="kt-user-card-v2">' +
                                '<div class="kt-user-card-v2__pic">' +
                                '<div class="kt-badge kt-badge--xl kt-badge--primary">KW</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="kt-user-card-v2__details">' +
                                '<a href="#" class="kt-user-card-v2__name">' + data.name + '</a>' +
                                '<span class="kt-user-card-v2__desc">' + data.role + '</span>' +
                                '<span class="kt-user-card-v2__desc"></span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</div>';
                            }
                            
    
                            return output;
                        }
                    }, {
                        field: "mc_name",
                        title: "Market Center",
                        sortable: false,
                    }, {
                        field: "megaagent_name",
                        title: "Mega Agente",
                        sortable: false,
                    },{
                        field: "kw_start_date",
                        title: "Ingreso KW",
                        sortable: false,
                    }, {
                        field: "kw_en_date",
                        title: "Salida KW",
                        sortable: false,
                    },{
                        field: "status",
                        title: "Estado",
                        sortable: false,
                        template: function (t) {
                            var e = {
                                Activo: {
                                    title: "Activo",
                                    class: " kt-badge--success"
                                },
                                Inactivo: {
                                    title: "Inactivo",
                                    class: " kt-badge--danger"
                                }
                            };
                            return '<span class="kt-badge ' + e[t.status].class + ' kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill">' + e[t.status].title + "</span>"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }),

        $("#kt_market_center_dropdown").on("change", function () {
            $(".kt-datatable").KTDatatable("reload");
            console.log($("#kt_market_center_dropdown option:selected").val());
        }),

        $("#kt_mega_agent_dropdown").on("change", function () {
            $(".kt-datatable").KTDatatable("reload");   
        }),

        $("#kt_team_dropdown").on("change", function () {
            $(".kt-datatable").KTDatatable("reload");
        }),

        $("#kt_form_exclusive").on("change", function () {
            $(".kt-datatable").KTDatatable("reload");
        }),

        $("#kt_form_open").on("change", function () {
            $(".kt-datatable").KTDatatable("reload");
        }),

        $("#kt_form_sale").on("change", function () {
            $(".kt-datatable").KTDatatable("reload");
        }),

        $("#kt_form_rent").on("change", function () {
            $(".kt-datatable").KTDatatable("reload");
        })
    }
    
};
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    KTDatatableChildRemoteDataDemo.init()
});
```

Comment: I think that it's because you have a "reload" trigger when user changes this option. Once it reloads it won't find any selected option in element kt_market_center_dropdown, right? I'd check to see if the seleced option exists before using .val()

Comment: Thanks @PedroSilveira for you reply. If I console.log after the reload, the value is returned correctly, so it looks that is not an issue in that code line.
I believe is an issue on nested functions ajax calls but I can't get it solved,

Comment: I think that since it's a GET request you can change params: { query: {...} } to only: data: {...} unless you set processData = false. 
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ 
let me know if it works so I create an answer :)

Comment: thanks @PedroSilveira that worked!

Comment: Cool! Sent the answer. By accepting and upvoting it, you'd also help who helped you :) appreciate it, best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a **GET** request you can change

`params: { query: {...} }`

to only:

`data: {...}`

unless you set `processData = false`.

Reference: [api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)